# How to run my Vue app if have inside private registry package?

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-install, npm-registry

I cloned a Vue app from git which I am trying to install npm install command, but this gives me the following error:

```
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for bekit@1.0.44.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'scoring-frontend'
npm ERR! notarget 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/obidjon/.npm/_logs/2022-07-21T05_54_41_930Z-debug.log
```

My package.json files is as follows:

```
  "name": "scoring",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "bekit": "npm i bekit --registry http://localhost:4888"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bekit": "^1.0.44",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "ky": "^0.27.0",
    "precss": "^4.0.0",
    "v-calendar": "^2.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.24.2",
    "vue-recaptcha": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.6",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

**Scripts** in package.json have bekit registry  and it cannot be installed.

I try to install bekit from npmjs which is https://www.npmjs.com/package/bekit
( *npm i bekit*). But This is completely different.

How to use this private registry which is bekit ????

Comment: The package doesnt seem to be private. The issue may be that you try to install bekit version 1.0.44 but the latest bekit version is 0.1.5

Comment: No,  https://www.npmjs.com/package/bekit - this is other library . My projects inside bekit is not related to this. I already  install 0.1.5 . But this bekit is other.

Comment: in that case you may want to have a `.npmrc` file in your root folder (if your private package is registered at npmjs)

and add the following

`save-exact=true`
`//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=<YOUR_NPM_TOKEN>`
```

This should help npm to also get the packages from your private repos.

Comment: This private package is not mine. This vue app already running. Only i must change some part in this project, But i cannot run project. I dont know developer who is write this project. 

What can i do ?

Comment: `
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "bekit": "npm i bekit --registry http://localhost:4888"
  },

Comment: `"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "bekit": "npm i bekit --registry http://localhost:4888"
  }, ` 
 Scripts and have bekit with localhost registry 
`"bekit": "npm i bekit --registry http://localhost:4888"`

How can I use , example npm run bekit or other ?

Comment: Seems like the owner of the project had a registry running for bekit on his local machine to install it. If you do not have access to it you probably wont be able to run `npm i` as long as the private package is there. The purpose of a package being private is ofc that not everyone has access to it.

Comment: Thank you, i understand. This project now  is running server.  If i get access to server, What I do? Copy .npmrc file ? or other do ?

Comment: If the Project is running on a server there must be a build process for it. 
That build process can only take place if the npm packages get installed -> which means that in the build process the package can be found. 
Figure out how it is done in the build process and you should be able to get it done on your local machine too :). 

Yes Probably you will need the .npmrc file with an private key

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.